# Can't get SQL statement to update from 2 Tables?

Tags: sql, sql-update

I currently have a database with two tables in it one hold lets say job details and the other company details. The "company_name" exists in the "Jobs" table which will have a matching entry in the "Companies" table under the field of "name". I want to basically set the field in the "Companies" table of "comp_id" to be the value of the field "id" in the "Jobs" table, WHERE the "name" in the "Companies" table is equals to the "company_name" in the "Jobs" table.

I have create the query below which i believed should work however it returns no rows affected?? can anyone please help me with this?

```
UPDATE `jobs`, `companies` 
       SET `comp_id` = 'companies.id' 
WHERE ('companies.name' = 'jobs.company_name')
```

Thanks

Comment: To my knowledge you can only update 1 table in 1 qeury.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your question you are only updating one table not two?

> I want to basically set the field in
>   the "Companies" table of "comp_id" to
>   be the value of the field "id" in the
>   "Jobs" table, WHERE the "name" in the
>   "Companies" table is equals to the
>   "company_name" in the "Jobs" table.

All you want to do is set the `comp_id` column in the `companies` table to the value of the `id` column in the `jobs` table where the `name` and `company_name` columns are the same?

To do this using MSSQL you would do something like this:

```
Update c
Set c.comp_id = j.Id
From dbo.Companies c
Join dbo.Jobs j on c.Name = j.Company_Name
```

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

WHERE ('companies.name' = 'jobs.company_name')

is one problem (unless this is a copy & paste error during posting)

You are comparing two string **literals** there (and of course as they are not the same, you will never update anything).

The reason is you are using single quotes which denote a string literal. To quote column names you either need to use double quotes or the backticks you had used before (assuming you are on MySQL).

Comment: +1 But MySQL *does* have a [multiple table update syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can update only 1 table in an UPDATE statement in SQL Server. To update multiple tables at once you have the following options:

1. Use Stored procs
2. Create a View of the select statement and delete from the view
3. Use triggers.

Comment: Hi,

I have actually now solved this issue myself with the MySQL query below:

    UPDATE jobs, companies SET jobs.comp_id = companies.id WHERE jobs.company_name = companies.name

Thanks